# Scroll a content in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to scroll a content in a TextView, this is the code that sets the results to be displayed in a TextView:

```
do
{                   
y = m;
f = x / y;
m = (y + f) / 2;
str[i] = x + "\t " + y + "\t " + f + "\t " + m + "\t";                  
i++;
a = i;

} while (Math.abs(y - m) >= 0.00001 * y);               
str4 = numfmt1.format(y);
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++){
ris.append(str[j] + "\n");//TextView that contains the string str
}
ris.append("La radice è: " + str4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the TextView inside the ScrollView. But make careful as ScrollView can hold only one child.... and the TextView will be the child of the ScrollView. Do this using the xml or graphical layout functionality in eclipse.

```
<ScrollView>

   TextView

</ScrollView>
```